# How to get Scrolltop() value for inline css overflow-y:auto effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

The div looks like this

```
<div class="nestedDemo" ng-include="'test.html'" style="height: 500px; 
 overflow-y: auto;"></div>
```

I want to get scrolltop value for this div as the div has scrollbar after adding other div's to it(drag-drop function).

Js code looks like this, but the value of scrollValue is always 0 even there is a scroll available.

```
var scrollValue = $('.nestedDemo').scrollTop();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var scrollValue = $('.nestedDemo').scrollTop();
//the value is never change;
//when the div has scrollbar after adding other div's to it(drag-drop function).
//you need get the value once again. 
// if you remove a children , get the value once again .
```

Comment: I am handling the the changes by calling function to update the scroolValue, its working elsewhere but not for inline style.

Comment: @ninjafrontendcoder   oh,maybe you should not use inline style